# Any Java debugging tips for finding the cause of "Too Many Files Open"

Tags: java, debugging, stream, filenotfoundexception

I'm developing in a linux environment and the system is intended to run continuously over a long period of time. After an overnight test we see the FileNotFoundException with a message of "Too Many Files Open". We started logging the output of the lsof command at various times in the system to see if we can see what is happening. We noticed lots of unnamed pipes opened. So I figured these were due to File Streams not getting closed. I searched through the source for any *Stream objects used and made sure they were all getting closed in a finally{} block. Are there any other Java object types that I could search for that I might not be closing that would cause all these unnamed pipes to be opened?

Also, my ulimit is 1024 and I also searched for *Writer and made sure those were all closing too.

Comment: Unnamed pipes? Can you paste a sample line of the lsof output? Are you using any third party libraries that could possibly be part of the problem?

Comment: Also, are you creating any tmp files? .... and why not try to increase the ulimit as well.

Comment: Look for Sockets as well... These use file descriptors as well (at least on UNIXes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[YourKit](http://www.yourkit.com/overview/index.jsp) might be worth a look. Its [probes](http://www.yourkit.com/docs/90/help/builtin_probes.jsp) are meant to help with this type of problems, although I've never had the occasion to try that functionality myself.

Comment: After doing research on YourKit and other profilers I realized that the IDE I was using actually has a profiler built-in. We ended up finding the problem before messing around with any profiler but it looks like those profiling tools are definitely the way to go in the future. I'll have to play around with one whenever I get the time. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: So what was the root cause of the problem?

Comment: 5 Years later now I can't remember what the problem ended up being. My vague recollection was that it was something stupid. We were doing a ton of threading and the complexity of the project really got out of hand which definitely made it harder to identify the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your ulimit is the output of ulimit -n. 1024 is a fairly small number of file descriptors to allow for in a production system. For a debugging step, rather than running lsof at random times and trying to correlate, why not catch the FileNotFound exception and run a Runtime.exec("lsof") and print the output to a log file to get a fairly accurate view of exactly what file descriptors were used when the problem occurred.

Comment: I think Runtime.exec might use pipes to get stdin / stdout. In that case it wouldn't work anymore when file descriptors run out.

Comment: That's a good point. I'm almost positive you're right about using stdin and stdout pipes, but if it's an intermittent problem where you are often close to the limit and occasionally hit it, triggering the FileNotFound exception, it could possible still work in practice if you put a short sleep before checking lsof.

Comment: @extraneon is correct. Runtime.exec won't work for the lsof command once we hit the FileNotFound exception. That is why we were doing it periodically during the code.

Answer (score 0):

Other classes that might leak file descriptors are `FileChannel` and `RandomAccessFile` - the latter doesn't even seem to have a finalizer, so its leaks might be permanent.